# Where is official documentation about locking mechanisms for etckeeper, apt, and/or dpkg?

Tags: apt, dpkg, documentation, lock, etckeeper

**Context:**

Want to put a lock on *etckeeper/apt* hook activity during special backup.

Objective is to preserve whole package integrity, e.g., wait until any package installation is complete, and then prevent new installation from starting until special backup is complete.

Found shell script under *cron* which appears to be attempting to a lock on

```
/var/cache/etckeeper/packagelist.pre-install
```

but actually it is not performed atomically and so it is flawed.  I presume the *cron* shell script is part of *Ubuntu 16.04* installation, not a part of *etckeeper* release.  **Flawed lock code shown below.**

Searched for *etckeeper* documentation about use of `/var/cache/etckeeper/packagelist.pre-install` as lock file.  Found no documentation.  But did find a piece of script file which writes to `/var/cache/etckeeper/packagelist.pre-install` without treating it as a lock file.  At this time I am presuming that `/var/cache/etckeeper/packagelist.pre-install` is not intended to serve as a lock file interface for *etckeeper*.  **Etckeeper internal script not treating 
`/var/cache/etckeeper/packagelist.pre-install` as a lock file shown below.**

**Question 1: Is there (and if so where is) documentation on etckeeper locking mechanism, or a developers portal to issue a requestion for clarification?**

There are plenty of questions and much discussion on *stackexchange* sites about the use of

```
/var/lib/apt/lists/lock    (we call it apt lock below)
```

and

```
/var/lib/dpkg/lock     (we call it dpkg lock below)
```

as locks for *apt* and *dpkg* respectively.  All of the communications are concerned with stuck locks, how to diagnose them, and how to unstick them.  However, I kind find no references to official *apt* and *dpkg* documentation specifying those lock files use as a formal interface.

**Question 2:  Is there (and if so where is) documentation on *apt* lock mechanism and/or *dpkg* lock mechanism as public interfaces?**

Flawed lock attempt shell script, probably provided by *Ubuntu 16.04*:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/cron.daily/etckeeper
#!/bin/sh
set -e
if [ -x /usr/bin/etckeeper ] && [ -e /etc/etckeeper/etckeeper.conf ]; then
    . /etc/etckeeper/etckeeper.conf
    if [ "$AVOID_DAILY_AUTOCOMMITS" != "1" ]; then
        # avoid autocommit if an install run is in progress
        lockfile=/var/cache/etckeeper/packagelist.pre-install
        if [ -e "$lockfile" ] && [ -n "$(find "$lockfile" -mtime +1)" ]; then
            rm -f "$lockfile" # stale
        fi
        if [ ! -e "$lockfile" ]; then
            AVOID_SPECIAL_FILE_WARNING=1
            export AVOID_SPECIAL_FILE_WARNING
            if etckeeper unclean; then
                etckeeper commit "daily autocommit" >/dev/null
            fi
        fi
    fi
fi
```

*Etckeeper* internal shell scipt writing to `packagelist.pre-install` and not treating it as a lock - hence I don't think it was intended as a lock interface.

```
$ sudo cat /etc/etckeeper/pre-install.d/10packagelist 
#!/bin/sh
# This list will be later used when committing.
mkdir -p /var/cache/etckeeper/
etckeeper list-installed > /var/cache/etckeeper/packagelist.pre-install
etckeeper list-installed fmt > /var/cache/etckeeper/packagelist.fmt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The cron job is treating `/var/cache/etckeeper/packagelist.pre-install` as evidence that an installation is being processed, so it shouldn’t archive anything just yet. That file isn’t supposed to be a lock file, but the cron job is using it as a substitute.

   However I wouldn’t particularly worry about `etckeeper` and any lock files it has or hasn’t. If you want a consistent backup of an `etckeeper` managed tree, use the VCS’s features (but don’t forget any ignored files).
2. The `dpkg` locks are documented (albeit briefly) as public interfaces in [`frontend.txt`](https://salsa.debian.org/dpkg-team/dpkg/blob/master/doc/frontend.txt) (`/usr/share/doc/dpkg-dev/frontend.txt` in `dpkg-dev`).

Comment: Upon the installation of a single package and all of its dependencies, is there a single atomic git commit to update the state of the repository?  If the preceding add  can be ignored, and the commit is atomic, then there is no need for a lock.  But if there were multiple commits, then there would be something to worry about.  I couldn't find that discussed in the very brief etckeeper documentation.

Comment: Every `apt` (or related) run is followed by a single `etckeeper` commit (if necessary) containing all the changes made to `/etc`. The “lock” is used so that the cron job won’t perform a commit if there’s already an `etckeeper` operation in progress (`apt` won’t ever run two `etckeeper` commits, but `apt` and cron jobs can run in parallel).